# mysql in query with number/string return unexpected result

Tags: mysql

The field `cookingMethod` is `varchar`. When I pass the number parameter: `in(3,4)` why do I get this result?

```
SELECT distinct(cookingMethod) FROM recipe where cookingMethod in(3, 4);
```

Result: `[3][3,5][3,4][4][4,5]`

[image]

and if I use `('3','4')`, the result is only `'3','4'`?

```
SELECT distinct(cookingMethod) FROM recipe where cookingMethod in('3', '4')
```

Result: `[3][4]`

Comment: Now what is your problem anyway?

Comment: not yet, 
    SELECT distinct(cookingMethod) FROM cms.recipe where cookingMethod = 3

    result : [3,1,5] [3,5] [3]

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is simple, and returns the expected result, because you are comparing strings with strings.

In your first query, however, you are using numbers for comparison with strings.  MySQL implicitly tries to convert the value of the field into a number to perform the comparison (where other databases might just have thrown an error). However, since there field has both numbers and commas, MySQL treats it as a `BLOB` with a comma-separated list of numbers, for purposes of this query. The `IN` operator will search through a comma-separated list, and therefore it matches every field that has either a `3` or a `4` within it's comma-separated list of numbers.